# Number of zeros

Tags: complex-analysis, polynomials

How to find number of zeros of polynomial $f(z)=z^{13}-2z^7+10z^3-z+4$ in ring $P=\{z:1\leq |z|<2\}$?

Number of zeros in B(0,2) is 13 and there is no zeros in B(0,1). Therefore, number of zeros is 13. Am I right?

Any help is welcome.
Thanks in advance.

Comment: Are you familiar with Rouche's theorem?

Comment: See what Anurag said.  This is why we want more than just a question, we want context.  So, as originally stated, we do now know: did you learn Rouché but did not think of using it here?  Or do you not know Rouché's theorem at all?  Or did you try Rouché's theorem but did not get an answer?

Comment: @GEdgar I did try Rouche theorem and got answer 13 zeros, is it okay?

Comment: That is exactly the sort of thing that should be included in the question, together with your reasoning.  It has 13 zeros below 2, but some of them are below 1.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No, that is incorrect.

On $\lvert z\rvert=1$, we have $g(z)=10z^3$ satisfies $\lvert g(z)\rvert=10$, $\lvert f(z)-g(z)\rvert\leq 8<\lvert g(z)\rvert$.  So Rouché's gives $f$ has as many roots as $g$ inside the unit disc with multiplicity, i.e., 3 roots.